# recursion trees and big theta bounds

Tags: recursion, discrete-mathematics

Draw recursion trees and use them to find big theta bounds on the solutions to the following recurrences. For each, assume that T(1) = 1 and that n is a power of the appropriate integer. ex) T(n) = 8T(n-2) + n

There are multiple equations that I have to do with the above directions. I am lost on finding big theta bounds. I would prefer examples since I learn easiest that way. Thank you for any help!

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking.  If you are asking us to solve your exercise for you, we discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out.  If not, then I suggest you delete that exercise, as it's not very helpful.  Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about?  (cont.)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.  Also, what research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research/self-study before asking, and to show us in the question what you've done.  Have you looked at our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/), or used the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered?  There are *lots* of examples on this site, and in standard textbooks and online.

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1682/755.